# Validate each line using a single regex

Tags: java, regex

I am writing an application in Java that is supposed to communicate to an external device. The device responds using the following format

```
01 02 05 0A 2D 3E
01 02 12 2B 09 07
```

As a response I may get at least one line, but often there are several.

I tried to validate the response using a simple regular expression

```
([0-9a-fA-F]{2} ?){6}\r
```

But it returns true if at least one line is correct, and I need to validate all lines.
I know that I may split the response into separate lines and validate each in a loop, but the question is - is it possible to validate all lines using a single regex?

**Update** (the Java code I am using):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9a-fA-F]{2} ?){6}\r");
String string = "01 02 05 qA 2D 3E\r01 02 12 2B 09 07\r"; // qA - 4th number is invalid

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: `it returns true if at least one line is correct` can we see code you are using?

Comment: Sorry for waiting. I posted answer which should explain problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it returns true if at least one line is correct

It is because `find` method is trying to find substring in your input which can be matched by your regex. If you want to check if entire input is matched my regex use `matches()`.

Also, your regex

```
([0-9a-fA-F]{2} ?){6}\r
```

can only match one line which ends with `\r`. To let regex accept more lines simply put it in parenthesis and add `+` after it

```
(([0-9a-fA-F]{2} ?){6}\r\n?)+
```

I added optional `\n` after `\r` in case line separators could be `\r\n`. You can also use `(\r\n?|$)` in case last line will not contain line separators

Last thing is that as you already know your code example contains `q` instead of `0` which prevents regex from matching.

So try this way

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:([0-9a-fA-F]{2} ?){6}\r)+");
String string = "01 02 05 0A 2D 3E\r01 02 12 2B 09 07\r"; 

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! From your code I see that my problem was that I used the wrong method `find()` instead of `match()`.